# How to pass parameter from one component to another

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components

I have some components, which together form my menu. I'm wanting to get a parameter in the topmost component, and use it in the lower components.

I want to pass the 'app-rest' value to my component.

```
angular.module('app').component('application', {
        controller: applicationController,
        template: `
        <cp-layout 
            config="$ctrl.config" 
            menu="$ctrl.menu" 
            clientId="$ctrl.clientId"
            logout="$ctrl.logout()">
            <div ui-view class="content-wrapper ng-scope ng-fadeInRight"></div>
        </cp-layout>
        `
    });

 applicationController.$inject = [ '$window', '$http', 'MensagemService', '$filter', 'Siseg' ];
    function applicationController($window, $http, MensagemService, $filter, Siseg) {
        const vm = this;

        vm.$onInit = function() {
          vm.clientId = 'app-rest';
}
```

this is cp-layout:

```
    (function() {
        'use strict';

        angular.module('cp.layout', ['cp.navbar', 'cp.sidebar'])

        .component('cpLayout', {
            bindings : {
                config: '<',
                logout: '&?',
                menu: '<?',
                menuFile: '<?',
                clientId: '@'
            },
            replace: true,
            transclude: true,
            template : `
            <div data-ng-class="{ 'layout-fixed' : $ctrl.config.layout.isFixed, 'aside-collapsed' : $ctrl.config.layout.isCollapsed, 'layout-boxed' : $ctrl.config.layout.isBoxed, 'layout-fs': $ctrl.config.layout.useFullLayout, 'layout-h': $ctrl.config.layout.horizontal, 'aside-float': $ctrl.config.layout.isFloat,'aside-toggled': $ctrl.config.layout.asideToggled}">

   <cp-navbar config="$ctrl.config" logout="$ctrl.logout()"></cp-navbar>

        {{$ctrl.clientId}} / Nothing is printed here.
                <cp-sidebar class="aside lateral-sidebar" config="$ctrl.config" menu="$ctrl.menu" menu-file="$ctrl.menuFile" clientId="$ctrl.clientId"></cp-sidebar>

                <div class="content-layer m-b-1">
                    <ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
                </div>
            </div>
            `
        });

    })();
```

Comment: For your topmost component's definition add a property called  `controllerAs: 'topCtrl'` (for example) and to access something from this controller inside childrend use `topCtrl.someProperty`

Comment: @AdityaParab Components bind their controllers to `$ctrl` by default. For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Directive Definition vs Component Definition](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#comparison-between-directive-definition-and-component-definition)

Comment: Yes.. I am aware of that. from the question, it is not clear how many levels down the data needs to be accessed from. For one level, your answer is correct. but for the scenarios where there are more than one level, you can override the value of `controllerAs` to be able to access it parent controller from the arbitrary number of level down the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [kebab-case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case#Special_case_styles) in the template:

```
angular.module('app').component('application', {
    controller: applicationController,
    template: `
    <cp-layout 
        config="$ctrl.config" 
        menu="$ctrl.menu" 
        ̶c̶l̶i̶e̶n̶t̶I̶d̶=̶"̶$̶c̶t̶r̶l̶.̶c̶l̶i̶e̶n̶t̶I̶d̶"̶
        client-id="$ctrl.clientId"
        logout="$ctrl.logout()">
        <div ui-view class="content-wrapper ng-scope ng-fadeInRight"></div>
    </cp-layout>
    `
});
```

And use [one-way `<` binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-) in the component:

```
app.component('cpLayout', {
    bindings : {
        config: '<',
        logout: '&?',
        menu: '<?',
        menuFile: '<?',
        ̶c̶l̶i̶e̶n̶t̶I̶d̶:̶ ̶'̶@̶'̶
        clientId: '<'
    },
```

For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Component-based application architecture](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture).